# Google Drive api (PHP) the apiDriveService class is missing

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I just downloaded the latest Google API PHP client library (0.5.0) there:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/downloads/detail?name=google-api-php-client-0.5.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=

And the class apiDriveService  is not in the code and the file is missing in contrib where i can find it?

The link is mentioned on the Google Drive SDK documentation there : https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads

So i don't understand

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it here:

- http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/apiDriveService.php
- https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/#hg%2Fphp%2Flibs%2Fgd-v2-php%2Fcontrib

Comment: Merci je suis Belge aussi au passage tiens! :D ;)

Comment: Ravie d'aider un compatriote/Happy to help a fellow citizen!

Comment: If you have problems with sending a doc to Google Drive with the current api (which was my case), you should check here the last version of the google-api-client: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/#src%253Fstate%253Dclosed